# Scrapy query is returning an empty list

Tags: html, web, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I want to scrape a website to the links. 
https://www.rentomojo.com/mumbai/furniture/bedroom-furniture-on-rent
[image]

The link is the href link inside div. 
My scrapy code is

```
response.css("div.col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-mgbtm a::attr(href)").extract()
```

but this does not work.

I even tried using xpath

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-mgbtm']/a/@href").extract()
```

But this also does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your xpath code in bash:

```
scrapy shell https://www.rentomojo.com/mumbai/furniture/bedroom-furniture-on-rent
response.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-mgbtm']/a/@href").extract()
```

and it work fine.

Code with css

```
response.css("div.col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-mgbtm a::attr(href)").extract()
```

return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write `response.css(".col-xs-6 ::attr(href)").extract()`

No need to write `HTML` tags within the selector when the class or `id` is present. Similarly no need to write `a` tag `::attr(href)` is enough for extracting links.